# Shortcut for splitting only once in C#?

Tags: c#, string, split

Okay, lets say I have a string:

```
string text = "one|two|three";
```

If I do `string[] texts = text.Split('|');` I will end up with a string array of three objects. However, this isn't what I want. What I actually want is to split the string only once... so the two arrays I could would be this:

```
one
two|three
```

Additionally, is there a way to do a single split with the last occurrence in a string? So I get:

```
one|two
three
```

As well, is there a way to split by a string, instead of a character? So I could do `Split("||")`

Comment: you could just `String.Concat` the rest of the strings back together

Comment: Yes, for the [first one](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c1bs0eda(v=vs.110).aspx), no for the second.

Comment: On your last question: String.Split has an overload that allows you to pass an array of strings to split by rather than a character array (you have to use a StringSplitOptions enumeration). See here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tabh47cf(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your first scenario, you can pass a parameter of how many strings to split into.

```
var text = "one|two|three";
var result = text.Split(new char[] { '|' }, 2);
```

Your second scenario requires a little more magic.

```
var text = "one|two|three";
var list = text.Split('|');
var result = new string[] { string.Join("|", list, 0, list.Length - 1), list[list.Length - 1] };
```

Code has not been verified to check results before using.

Comment: Fixed the starting index on the join.

Answer (score 7):

[Split](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c1bs0eda%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method takes a count as parameter, you can pass `2` in that position, which basically says that you're interested in only `2` elements maximum. You'll get the expected result.

For second question: There is no built in way AFAIK. You may need to implement it yourself by splitting all and joining first and second back.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I do mostly PHP and Perl... so I come from languages that have shortcuts for everything.

Answer (score 4):

C#'s [`String.Split()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c1bs0eda(v=vs.110).aspx) can take a second argument that can define the number of elements to return:

```
string[] texts = text.Split(new char[] { '|' }, 2);
```

Comment: it's not an optional argument.it's another overloaded version of Split.there is a big difference.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I took it as a challenge to do your second one in one line. The result is... not pretty, mostly because it's surprisingly difficult to reverse a string and keep it as a string.

```
string text = "one|two|three";

var result = new String(text.Reverse().ToArray()).Split(new char[] {'|'}, 2).Reverse().Select(c => new String(c.Reverse().ToArray()));
```

Basically, you reverse it, then follow the same procedure as the first one, then reverse each individual one, as well as the resulting array.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do like this as well...

```
  //To split at first occurence of '|'


  if(text.Containts('|')){
  beginning = text.subString(0,text.IndexOf('|'));

  ending = text.subString(text.IndexOf('|');
  }

  //To split at last occurence of '|'
  if(text.Contains('|')){
   beginning = text.subString(0,text.LastIndexOf('|'));

  ending = text.subString(text.LastIndexOf('|');
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Second question was fun. I solved it this way:

```
    string text = "one|two|three";

    var result = 
        new []
        {
            string.Concat(text.ToCharArray().TakeWhile((c, i) => i <= text.LastIndexOf("|"))),
            string.Concat(text.ToCharArray().SkipWhile((c, i) => i <= text.LastIndexOf("|")))
        };
```